# No Applications Showing In Ubuntu 18.04. Even Search is not working

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, search

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my Dell 7559 and I have reinstalled it too but still when I click on "Show Applications" it's empty.

[image: No Applications Screenshot]

Even Search is not working too. Whenever I search for something it shows "Searching" forever.

[image: Shows Searching forever]

It sometimes works if restart but same problem after sometime.

Device: Dell 7559
Distro: Ubuntu 18.04 x64
Kernel: #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018
Theme: Nebulossa with Flat remix dark miami

Comment: I have this issue under Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue in 19.10. Uninstalling the communitheme theme fixed it for me

```
$ sudo apt remove ubuntu-communitheme-session
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after updating to Ubuntu 18.10. For me it was a gnome shell extension that caused the issue (maybe it is no longer supported). In my case the extension was "Workspace Isolated Dash". Deleting this extension helped. You can do this with

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-isolated-dash@n-yuki
```

(Thanks to https://forum.antergos.com/topic/10693/gnome-shell-applications-empty-after-update-to-gnome-3-30/3)

Comment: I tried this on 19.10 (deleting all extensions there) and it didn't help.